# Loading a Localized UIImage

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, image, localization, uiimage

I need to load localized images in my iOS app, but also have to take into account that they might need to be the `...@2x` kind. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Corrected Answer**

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"TestImage"]` looks first into Resources, if nothing found, it then looks in the lproj dir folders. So you only need to put the localized images into the right folder.

***Old Answer***

[NSLocalizedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) should do the trick. See [Localizing String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005).

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"TestImage",@"")];
```

Comment: No, I mean the image is localized, not the name. I have a resource in `en.lproj` and one in `es.lproj`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how to simple load the image when it's in a *.lproj folder. Using the method above you would have all the image in your resource folder with a suffix like TestImage-es.png and map them in the string file.