# IOS Localization after startup

Tags: ios, localization

I'm trying to localize an ios app after it was launched.
We should be able to select the desired language on the startup screen.

The app is already localized and available for 13 languages.
The only solution I found is to set the locale and relaunch the app, but we can't really do that, as it's not user friendly, and Apple will probably reject it.

The project contains most of a thousand of xib files, so I can't change all the resources "manually" either.

Is there any solution to reload the UIApplication ? Or an other trick to change the locale on the fly (and allowed by Apple) ?

I found lots of threads which were talking about this, but none very interesting compared to the scale of the project.

Comment: I had same problem. In my app i am letting user change his language though apps setting. I replaced NSLocalizedString by my custom #define format using just find replace (this takes care that changing lang from iOS setting will not affect) and i access same localizable files which were i using before by NSBunble mainbundle. When user choose another language i post notification and refresh all UI components (refreshing was tricky as my app is bit complex)

Comment: Can your users changes the language in all state of your app ?
What makes me crazy is that my users will just be able to change the language at the startup, before any login attempt.

No problem for android, language choice done in 1 hours. I will need one week to do that on IOS ..
Its seems to be the only solution to do that, but if I set all the resources "manually", the IOS Localization system will be useless.. 
Thanks for your help :) , I hope Apple will change that in IOS 22..

Comment: yes. Your case looks more simple as you have not loaded all views for you its just login screen which need to refresh immediately

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want without coming up with a custom solution. I found a solution on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app) where a user created his own localization solution.