# Changing language of iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to programmatically change the language of the app i'm developing. 
I am using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But the titles of my UITabBar and UINavigationBar only change when i restart the app. Is there a solution for this? Is there a way to "refresh" this data?

Comment: Why are you changing this in the app? Normally, localization is adjusted by the user through the Settings app.

Comment: Im looking for this too but ios caches the language bundle... somehow we have to get it to reload its data :D

Comment: This is a feature the cliënt wants. :)

Comment: @KornelitoBenito exactly the same here :D

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app?rq=1

Comment: @KhawarAli the problem is with screens/ui elements that come from the OS

Comment: yes. I know those 2 lines change the language, this works. I only need a work around so i don't have to restart the app. (reload the uitabbars and uinavigationbars..)