# Can I programatically change the Localizable.strings file on button click with out restarting the app

Tags: ios, swift, localization, swift4

I am creating an app which uses 2 languages Arabic and English. I have managed to change the layout to RTL for Arabic and normal for English. Also I have added the Localizable.strings file for Arabic and English.

The app picks up English and normal layout shows when English is selected and picks up Arabic and RTL layout is shown when the app is started the first time or on every restart.

It does not pick up Arabic or English  Localizable.strings file on runtime. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: How to change app language programmatically WITHOUT restarting the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app)

Comment: Yes you can, In short you can use `NSLocalizedString("your localizable KEy",tableName: "NameOFYourLocalizableStringFileForThatLanguage", comment: "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the current bundle you read from

```
extension String {
      func localizedStr(language:String) -> String {
          let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj")
          let bundleName = Bundle(path: path!)
          return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundleName!, value: "", comment: "")

    }
}
```

In Action
[image]
[image]
[image]

see demo here  [local](https://github.com/ShKhan9/local)

Comment: does not work
I have added below code to text:

`StringClass.sharedInstance.lcstr_tenperoff.localizedStr(language: Constants.sharedInstance.LANGUAGE)`

Comment: Constants.sharedInstance.LANGUAGE should be language code ??

Comment: check your project folder whether contains folder named ar ??

Comment: no .. does not contain ar named folder.
I have Localizable.strings
Localizable.strings (English)
Localizable.strings (Arabic)

Should I create ar folder and place files there

Comment: add arabic lang in capabilities

Comment: i have added Arabic to Localization.
Where in Capabilities?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168217/discussion-between-yogesh-tandel-and-sh-khan).

Answer (score -1):

Try following code...it 
might help you to come out from your problem.

**Step 1**

```
extension String {

    /// Returns the localized string value
    public var localized: String {
        if let bundleName:String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "USER_LANG") as? String {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: bundleName, ofType: "lproj")
            let bundle = Bundle.init(path: path!)
            return localize(withBundle: bundle!)
        } else {
            return localize(withBundle: Bundle.main)
        }

    }

    public func localize(withBundle bundle: Bundle) -> String
    {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    }

}
```

**Step 2**

- Store the bundle name on a button click in user default.

**Example**

```
// Strore Base bundleName when english button is clicked
UserDefaults.standard.set("Base", forKey: "USER_LANG") 

// Strore fr(short from of french) bundleName when french button is clicked 
UserDefaults.standard.set("fr", forKey: "USER_LANG")
```

**Step 3**

**Usage**

- In String File

`"lbl_name"="name";`

```
// name will convert in French and English too
"lbl_name".localized
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: All of the above works with the XIB files but when i use values from string files it does not work.

Comment: Your string file should be like `"lbl_name" = "name"` and when you use this string you have to write like `"lbl_name".localized`.

Comment: // 
`
if L102Language.currentAppleLanguage() == "en" {
            L102Language.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "ar")
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            UserDefaults.standard.set("ar", forKey: "USER_LANG")
        } else {
            L102Language.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "en")
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            UserDefaults.standard.set("Base", forKey: "USER_LANG")
        }
`

Comment: I am using as given below
`lbl_Hotels.text = StringClass.sharedInstance.lcStr_bookahotel.uppercased().localized`