# Setting NSCameraUsageDescription programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a requirement to display a different camera permissions message, one for when the user starts the QR scanner, and one for taking a photo.

The user can start with either one, and product don't want to use a generic message for both.

Is there a way to set `NSCameraUsageDescription` programmatically, or can this only be done within `Info.plist`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the Info.plist of your app. You don't have write access to that file. In fact an app's bundle is read-only. You can't save changes to your bundle.

You should use a generic message mentioning both cases in the permission message. This way user knows that this permission will also be utilised in other places too.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, .plist files cannot be edited at runtime. Anyways they can be localized. It's possible to create multiple `Localizable.strings` files containing different values for your `NSCameraUsageDescription`.

Right after, you could change the localization file your app is pointing to, obtaining the correct text that will be displayed in the alert.

Comment: I doubt if apple approves this :(

Comment: Replacing localization strings at runtime is something that lots of applications do and there's nothing in the Developer Agreements that state such thing. That would be a totally viable approach :)

Comment: @LorenzoZanotto can you explain how to replace a localized InfoPlist.string my app is pointing to? thanks

Comment: I am concerned about apple and may be some users too might find out by doing this we are hiding out what our apps will exactly do with a permission. BTW I am also curious too know if this is feasible just for knowledge :)

Comment: @thedp you can take a look here, it explains how to change the bundle you're reading from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649199/can-i-programatically-change-the-localizable-strings-file-on-button-click-with-o

Comment: @LorenzoZanotto It seems they just get the string from the desired `Localizable.strings` file, but I need to tell the system which `InfoPlist.strings` to use. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the general message, you may present your customized alert message before request authorization somewhere, even with cooling animations.