# What happened to the `Localizable.strings` files on devices in recent versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, localization

In previous iOS versions, it was possible to access the localization of system resources on device by using the [Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) class.

For example, translating `Done` into German was possible using the following code:

```swift
let bundle = Bundle(url: Bundle(for: UINavigationController.self).url(forResource: "de", withExtension: "lproj")!)!
print(" \(bundle.bundleURL)")
for file in try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: bundle.bundleURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: []) {
    print("   \(file.lastPathComponent)")
}
let done = bundle.localizedString(forKey: "Done", value: "_fallback_", table: "Localizable")
print("Done in German: \(done)")
```

It was printing the following, just like expected:

```text
 file:///Applications/Xcode-14.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/de.lproj/
   Localizable.strings
   Localizable.stringsdict
   UITableViewLocalizedSectionIndex.plist
Done in German: Fertig
```

Note that this technique is still working on the simulators (for example iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 16.4) but is not working on actual devices.

When running this same code on an iPhone 11 running iOS 16.5.1 I get the following output:

```text
 file:///System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/de.lproj/
   UITableViewLocalizedSectionIndex.plist
Done in German: _fallback_
```

We can see that the translation fails because the `Localizable.strings` and `Localizable.stringsdict` have disappeared.

What happened to those files in recent iOS releases? Can we still access them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexandre Colucci informed me on Mastodon about the existence of a new [Localizable.loctable](https://hachyderm.io/@timac@mastodon.social/110855773190864052) file where all the localizations can be found.

With this knowledge I was able to write an extension method on the `Bundle` class to access localized strings from any bundle.

There are two implementations to get the dictionary of all localized strings. One that does not use a private API but uses the undocumented `.loctable` file format and one that uses the private `localizedStringsForTable:localization:` method.

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    public func localizedString(forKey key: String, localization: String, value: String? = nil, table tableName: String? = nil) -> String {
        if let localizedStrings = localizedStrings(forTable: tableName, localization: localization), let localizedString = localizedStrings[key] as? String {
            return localizedString
        } else if let url = url(forResource: localization, withExtension: "lproj"), let localizationBundle = Bundle(url: url) {
            return localizationBundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: tableName)
        }

        if let value, !value.isEmpty {
            return value
        }

        return key
    }

    private func localizedStrings(forTable tableName: String?, localization: String) -> [String: Any]? {
#if DISABLE_PRIVATE_API
        // This is not technically using a private API but it is using an undocument file and format
        let loctableURL = url(forResource: tableName ?? "Localizable", withExtension: "loctable")
        if let loctableURL, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: loctableURL) {
            let plist = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as? [String: [String: Any]]
            if let localizedStrings = plist?[localization] as? [String: Any] {
                return localizedStrings
            }
        }
#else
        // This is using a private API but one which is designed for this purpose
        let localizedStringsForTable = Selector(("localizedStringsForTable:localization:"))
        if responds(to: localizedStringsForTable), let localizedStrings = perform(localizedStringsForTable, with: tableName, with: localization)?.takeUnretainedValue() as? [String: Any] {
            return localizedStrings
        }
#endif
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage is straightforward and works on both simulators and devices for all versions of iOS.

```
let done = Bundle(for: UIApplication.self).localizedString(forKey: "Done", localization: "de")
print("Done in German: \(done)")
```

This prints `Done in German: Fertig` as expected.

Comment: Note that this technique along with some swizzling can be used to change the app language dynamically for both your main bundle but also for system bundles. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app/

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: "they moved".

These days, UIKit is technically multiple frameworks that look like a single framework. You can check this out yourself.

First, we need to find the "root" of the iOS simulator runtime, which we can do using the `find` command:

```
% cd /Applications/Xcode14_3_1.app
% find . -name 'RuntimeRoot'
./Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
```

This is the iOS runtime's equivalent of `/` for the simulator. You'll see the familiar-looking `System`, `Library`, `Developer`, `Applications`, etc folders.

Inside `System/Library/Frameworks`, you'll see the list of public frameworks. Inside `UIKit.framework`, you'll see the almost-entirely-empty UIKit contents. So where are they?

If you open the `UIKit` binary in a tool like Hex Fiend, you can view the structure of the file's Mach-O configuration:

[image: UIKit Mach-O structure]

See how there are a few `LC_REEXPORT_DYLIB` commands? That's a command that dyld uses to "pretend" that all the symbols coming from the specified framework (UIKitCore.framework, in the screenshot) should be treated as if they're coming from *this* framework.

In other words, the symbols all live in the private `UIKitCore.framework`, but your app thinks they're coming from `UIKit.framework`.

Because of this, when you ask the runtime for the `Bundle` that contains the `UINavigationController` class, it will report that it's coming from `UIKit.framework`, and not the *actual* `UIKitCore.framework`.

Since we know where the runtime root of the system is, we can manually check to see what's in that framework:

[image]

And what do you know… there are the localization files!

(insert standard caveat here about how relying on private stuff is not a good idea and can be fragile, as you've discovered)

---

TL;DR: The localization files are in the private `UIKitCore.framework`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but unfortunately this is not what is happening. I have edited my question to display the full URLs of the bundles and we see that `Bundle(for: UINavigationController.self)` returns the `UIKitCore.framework` bundle where the `Localizable`files are missing (but on devices only).