# imageNamed and localization issue

Tags: ios, localization, uiimage

I've localized my images via Xcode, and all the images are in the proper lproj folder.

However, when I use imageNamed I don't get the correct image, but I keep getting the default image even if I change language.

```
_myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
```

Comment: Could you put the code for getting the image here.

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3788068/1152596 It says that first looks into resources. Is it possible that you have a copy of the image into resources unlocalized? Luck.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that, and I checked that several times. Check the answer btw ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of issue made me waste some time, but then I realized it was a false issue and I hope to save you precious time.

If you switch language and the images are not in the new language, that's because of cached images. The documentation is straightforward:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists

Hence, when you switch language, and you ask for the same name to the cache, you'll get the old image! That's it. :)

Comment: So now is the question, how to reset that cache… (I tried cleaning the build, resetting the simulator even, and deleting the derived data.) I finally got it by removing one image in the localization it was 'stuck' in. Then the images were reloaded finally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
_myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
```

use:

```
NSString *imageName = NSLocalizedString(@"image_name", @"image_name");
_myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

and localize your image names using the Localizable.strings files like any other resource in your project.

Comment: I know there is this option, but I think it takes more time. You have to prepare the images as in the first solution, but then you have to put in each localizable.strings a new row. If you have n images and m languages, that's n*m lines. I agree it's mainly copy/paste, but yet it's more work.

Comment: It is more work, but its the right and recommended way of doing it :-)

Comment: I'm not sure it's the recommended way. In fact, it seems that the Apple documentation suggests to put localized images in the proper folders.

Comment: there is an option to localize an image. Just select it and click Localize in file inspector

Comment: yeah, that's what I did. I haven't put the images in the lproj folders by myself